# PHP - Assigning a value in IF statement - false if null

Tags: php, if-statement, null

I'm trying to simplify some code. I've found that if you assign a value within an if statement, but the value ends up being null, then the evaluated if is FALSE.

Example:

```
if($myvar = doSomething()) {   
    echo '$myvar = '.$myvar;
} 
else { 
    echo "was null"; 
}

function doSomething() { 
    $a = null;
    return $a; 
}
```

The script above will display "was null". However, if $a = 1, then it will display "myvar = 1".

I've tried to find some documentation around this behaviour but haven't been successful. All of my sources are close, but don't describe it well.

**My question:** Is this expected behaviour? If doSomething() returns null, is what I'm doing equivalent to `if(null) {...`?

**EDIT:** YES I mean '=' not '==' in the if statement. What I'm asking is it expected that this should always return false: `if($a = null)` whereas this returns true `if($a = 1)`

Comment: You did a mistake on this line, correct it this way:`if($myvar == doSomething())`

Comment: No, I mean it as an assignment

Comment: No, it is a mistake to run an assignment when testing with  if

Comment: But my question is whether or not this is expected behaviour, not if it is correct. Seems to me that this logic works.

Comment: Of course, if you run a mistake you can expect the unexpected. Read (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Comment: WOW, guys, what I'm trying to say is that my code returns TRUE if doSomething returns anything other than True - since it is an assignment. However, if doSomething returns null, then the assignment resolves to false and the else is executed. I'm just wondering if anyone knows if this is expected behaviour or not. Is `if ($a = null)` supposed to be false? WHY ALL THE HATE???

Comment: Setting it to `null` or `false` will evaluate as false as they're not truthy. `1` or `true` or any sort of string/int is truthy. You're doing an assignment but it's evaluating to whatever that function returns.

Comment: Addendum to the above as I can't edit after 5 minute, `0` will also be falsey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing is fully expected. The value of the assignment expression `$a=b` is the assigned value `b`. So,

```
if($myvar = doSomething()) { ...
```

is equivalent to

```
$myvar = doSomething();
if ($myvar) { ...
```

This behavior is completely unrelated to the `if` statement. [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) clearly states, in the second paragraph:

> The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned. That is, the value of "$a = 3" is 3.

Answer (score -2):

Try to call function in variable.

```
$getvar = doSomething();
if($myvar == $getvar) {
 // stuff
}
```

Comment: Only problem is if I have several if, ifelse... blocks and I don't want to do the work of doSomething() unless it gets that far... I understand that assigning a value inside an if is not good coding practice, I'm just wondering if this is expected or not.

Comment: So you can simply check using if condition. if($myvar == null) { }
No this is not going to be good. You have to match using comparison operator.